# Uploading multiple files in Liferay in application with two nodes

Tags: cookies, upload, liferay

I'm using Liferay 6.1.0 GA1.

My applications runs on two tomcats. I have varnish in front of them. Varnish redirect to particular node when cookie is set on it.

When I'm trying to upload multiples files on Firefox, it loses this cookie (on Chrome it works just fine).

My idea was, to extend URL - add parameter that can later be filtered in Varnish. But I cannot find where should I add this, that Flash can later copy this properly.

Any other ideas that will be helpful are welcome as well.

P.S. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Loosing a cookie" means that it explicitly is set to another value, or the hostname changes. I suggest you use Firebug or the built-in Developer tools (hit F12) and monitor the requests and responses that go through the line. Pay attention to `Set-Cookie` directives in the response headers as well as the `Host` directive in the request headers. This should give some hints where they're going.

It's hard to give more specific advice with the level of detail you provide.

Comment: I resolved this thanks to fixing set-cookie. Can You look into my another question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216400/using-recaptcha-in-liferay